# Compute value from more than three consecutive rows in awk

Tags: awk

I am working on a file like below:

```
site Date time value1 value2
0023 2014-01-01 00:00 32.0 23.7
0023 2014-01-01 01:00 38.0 29.9
0023 2014-01-01 02:00 85.0 26.6
0023 2014-01-01 03:00 34.0 25.3
0023 2014-01-01 04:00 37.0 23.8
0023 2014-01-01 05:00 80.0 20.3
0023 2014-01-01 06:00 90.0 20.0
0023 2014-01-01 07:00 180.0 20.0
0023 2014-01-01 08:00 30.0 20.0
```

The first column is site, second column is date (whole year of 2014), and third represent time (from 00:00 to 23:00 for each day), fourth and fifth columns are values. I need to compare column 4 and 5 based on the condition below:

For each site (column 1), if column 4 is more than 3 times of columns 5, and this pattern last for more than or equal 3 hours continually, plus the maximum of them must be higher than 100, print all the lines that meet the standard and count how many cases exist for each site.  There are totally around 150 sites and each site has hourly data each day. Here is the output I want:

```
0023 2014-01-01 05:00 80.0 20.3 1
0023 2014-01-01 06:00 90.0 20.0 1
0023 2014-01-01 07:00 180.0 20.0 1
0023 2014-06-30 23:00 200.0 30.3 2
0023 2014-07-01 00:00 303.0 30.3 2
0023 2014-07-01 01:00 134.0 30.3 2
0025 2014-07-01 01:00 136.0 25.3 1           
0025 2014-07-01 02:00 116.0 25.3 1
0025 2014-07-01 03:00 106.0 25.3 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: At the moment, this seems more like a specification than a question. Have you given anything a try already? If so, please [edit] to show us. Also, can you include the desired output?

Comment: Tom, thank you so much for quick response and help. I am pretty new to awk and I haven't got any hint on this although I tried to search for information but no clue. For output, I would like sth like

Comment: your input doesn't satisfy the condition you're testing.

Comment: Comments only allow very minimal formatting. Instead, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36651755/edit) your question to include the expected output.

Comment: @jas, thank you for telling me about that. Just add the output,but not sure how to remove the space between each line but still keep each line separate. Tom helped me edit the original part.

Comment: your input and output are not matching each other either.

Comment: For code and data samples, you just need to indent each line by four spaces (exactly as you have the input). Also make sure there's at least one empty line above the sample. A shortcut for indenting is to select the text and click the `{}` formatting button. With everything indented, the newlines will be respected and you can remove the double-spacing.

Comment: @jas, thank you for help. Just edited.

Comment: @karakfa, I made some change, is that clear now? Thank you.

Comment: @Kelly:If my answer was useful for your problem **please click the grey tick sign** on the left side of my answer.
If you interest to awk I can recommend this very classic book: Brian W. Kernighan, Alfred V. Aho, Weinberger :
The AWK Programming Language

Comment: Hi Kelly, you gave me this comment: "...It works. Thank you." 3 days ago. Please give me a green tick also according this link: [ http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826 ]
It will increase my reputations.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to guess what you had thought, first of all here is my test input:

```
#cat in2
```

.

```
This is the test input.
The 2nd and 3thd column can be any
so I didn't fill it now.

Abreviation: 3XCDT == "3 times $4>$5 condition"
           : because == bcs
site Date time value1 value2
0023 NC   NC   4.0  1.0
0023 NC   NC   4.0  1.0
0023 NC   NC   4.0  1.0
Next data ln breaks the 3XCDT
 but won't be prnt bcs mxvl<100 was.
00023 NC   NC   1.1  1.0 
00023 NC   NC   5.1  1.0 
00023 NC   NC   5.1  1.0 
00023 NC   NC   5.1  1.0 
Next data ln is new site
 but won't be prnt bcs mxvl<100 was.
00024 NC   NC   6.2  1.0 
00024 NC   NC   100.2  1.0 
00024 NC   NC   6.2  1.0 
Next data ln breaks the 3XCDT
 and will be prnt.
00024 NC   NC   1.1  1.0
00024 NC   NC   200.1  1.0
00024 NC   NC   200.1  1.0
Next data ln new site
 but won't be prnt bcs filo was smaller than 3
00025 NC   NC   7.1  1.1
00025 NC   NC   107.1  1.1
00025 NC   NC   7.1  1.1
Next data ln breaks the 3XCDT
 and will be prnt bcs mxvl>100 was.
00025 NC   NC   1.1  1.1
00025 NC   NC   8.1  1.1
00025 NC   NC   108.1  1.1
00025 NC   NC   8.1  1.1
No more data ln but the END condition
will prnt and see the counter will be 2
```

Output:

```
#./msr in2
00024 NC   NC   6.2  1.0  1
00024 NC   NC   100.2  1.0  1
00024 NC   NC   6.2  1.0  1
00025 NC   NC   7.1  1.1 1
00025 NC   NC   107.1  1.1 1
00025 NC   NC   7.1  1.1 1
00025 NC   NC   8.1  1.1 2
00025 NC   NC   108.1  1.1 2
00025 NC   NC   8.1  1.1 2
```

And my awk program: #cat msr

```
#!/bin/bash
(($#!=1))&& { echo "Usage $0 inp_file"; exit 1; }

awk '
 BEGIN {ix=0; stn=-1;}                             # ix: index of filo, stn: sitnum non-exist  
 $1~"[^0-9]" || NF!=5 || $4 $5 ~ "[^0-9.]" {next;} # skip no data lines

 $1 != stn  {chck_prnt(); stn=$1; stc=1;}          # new site, set counter to 1
 $4 < 3*$5  {chck_prnt(); next;}                   # broken the col4>3*col5
            {filo[ix++]=$0; if($4>mxvl)mxvl=$4;}   # put candidate data into filo & refresh mxvl
 END        {chck_prnt();}                         # no more data line

 #func for prnt if need it & clr filo, mxvl
 function chck_prnt(  i){                          # (i is a local var) 
    if(ix>=3 && mxvl>100){                         # prnt condition 
        for(i=0; i<ix; i++)printf("%s %d\n", filo[i],stc); # prnt all filo
        stc++;                                     # increas counter at site
    }
    ix=0; mxvl=0;                                  # clr filo & maxvl
 }
' $1
```

@Kelly,
Before I could change the code, I would need a further clarified specification.
Considering your newer example, pls tell me why need  to increase the counter (at the end of line)?

1. Because the date column has been changed (2014-01-01 --> 2014-01-02).
2. Or just we need to count each triple lines.If I see your firs example I would vote that you want to count the triplets line?

Other questions: Do I see well that time column (hh:mm) does not matter?
(because 3 lines is minimum 3 hours?)

Is 1 hour the elapsed time always between two consecutive lines (in a given site)?

(I thought from your first comment that everything was OK only you have forgotten to give the tick.)

/I think you can edit your first Question as many times, may be it is better than post newer Q./

Comment: László Szilágyi, thank you so much for help! You are my savior.

Comment: there is a problem with the code, I post it as an answer below because it is too long. Thank you.

Comment: László, thank you for your time and suggestion as well. Yes I want to count how many cases  that meet all the standards for each site. Maybe it will be easier if I just count all the cases (Not consider site name and only count how many events totally)? It is 1 hour elapsed time between two consecutive lines, however some period of time are missing as indicated in second sample.

Answer (score 1):

@Kelly, your comment wasn't an appropriate answer for my questions (in my opinion).
But I tried to guess what would be the real specification again.

I hope the key idea is:
When different time between two consecutive lines greater than
1 hour we also need to print the candidates (from filo) if the "standards" was true for them.

I needed to create a plus function to count the time differences.
And there is a plus line in the main part to call it when filo isn't empty.
And I also put a filter line to check the date and time format in the input.

Just note that:
My chk1h() function will be more then enough for this purpose,
but there are other possibilities to count of time difference between timestamps:

1/ maketime() function in gawk.

2/ bash shell date command e.g.: date "+%s" -d "2014-03-28 11:48:30"

I checked the program with your inputs and others and it was OK.

**If there is some problem yet, you need to give a longer and full representative input series.**
Don't give 2 lists (input and output).
Input list will be enough and write the appropriate site counter at the end of the lines to be displayed.
The lines not to be printed won't have 6th column.

cat msr2

```
#!/bin/bash
(($#!=1))&& { echo "Usage $0 inp_file"; exit 1; }
awk '
 BEGIN {ix=0; stn=-1;}                             # ix: index of filo, stn: non-exist
 $1~"[^0-9]" || NF!=5 || $4 $5 ~ "[^0-9.]" {next;} # skip no data lines
 $2 " " $3 !~ "^[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9].00$" {  # dt&tm format filtering
     printf("Unexpected dt,tm format:\nInput ln:%d\nContent: %s\n",NR,$0); exit(1);}

 $1 != stn  {chck_prnt(); stn=$1; stc=1;}          # new site, set counter to 1
 $4 < 3*$5  {chck_prnt(); next;}                   # broken the col4>3*col5
 ix         {if(!chk1h(ld, lt, $2, $3))chck_prnt();} # filo not empty-->need to chck 1h diff
            {filo[ix++]=$0; ld=$2; lt=$3;          # put into filo & set last dt,tm,mxvl
                            if($4>mxvl)mxvl=$4;}
 END        {chck_prnt();}                         # no more data line

 function chck_prnt(  i){                          # (i is a local var) 
    if(ix>=3 && mxvl>100){                         # prnt condition 
        for(i=0; i<ix; i++)printf("%s %d\n", filo[i],stc); # prnt all filo
        stc++;                                     # increase counter at site
    }
    ix=0; mxvl=0;                                  # clr filo & maxvl
 }

 function chk1h(d1,t1,d2,t2,  h1,h2,dy,dm,dd){     # ret 1 if dt of current ln - last dt in filo == 1h othrwise 0
   h1=substr(t1,1,2); h2=substr(t2,1,2);
   if(h2-h1==1 && d1==d2)return(1);                # most of case in same day 1h
   if(h1!=23||h2!="00")return(0);                  # not 1h
   split(d1,v1,"-"); split(d2,v2,"-");             # v1[1-3]=ymd last in filo, v2[1-3] current
   dy=v2[1]-v1[1];                                 # diff of year
   dm=v2[2]-v1[2];                                 # diff of month
   dd=v2[3]-v1[3];                                 # diff of day
   if(dd==1 && !dy && !dm)return(1);               # 23h-->00h 1h in same month
   if(v2[3]!="01")return(0);                       # not 1h
   if(v1[3]==31)                                   # chng of month, three type of prev month
       if(!dy && dm==1 || dy==1 && dm==-11)return(1); # 1h
       else return(0);                             # not 1h
   if(v1[3]==30)
       if("04 06 09 11" ~ v1[2] && !dy && dm==1)return(1); # 1h
       else return(0);                             # not 1h
   if("28 29" ~ v1[3] && v1[2]=="02" && !dy && dm==1)return(1); # 1h
   return(0);                                      # not 1h
 }
' $1
```

./msr2 in3

```
0023 2014-01-01 21:00 90.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-01 22:00 80.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-01 23:00 130.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-02 16:00 130.0 20 2
0023 2014-01-02 17:00 200.0 30.3 2
0023 2014-01-02 18:00 303.0 30.3 2
```

But if you want formatted output then run this way:

```
./msr2 in3|awk 'NF==6&&$1!~"[^0-9]"{printf("%s %s %s %6.1f %6.1f %3u\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);}'
```

.

```
0023 2014-01-01 21:00   90.0   20.0   1
0023 2014-01-01 22:00   80.0   20.0   1
0023 2014-01-01 23:00  130.0   20.0   1
0023 2014-01-02 16:00  130.0   20.0   2
0023 2014-01-02 17:00  200.0   30.3   2
0023 2014-01-02 18:00  303.0   30.3   2
```

Comment: In this case pls give me a green tick because you accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@László, there is a problem with the code: I just found the input isn't continuous, like the input below:

```
0023 2014-01-01 21:00 90.0 20
 0023 2014-01-01 22:00 80.0 20
 0023 2014-01-01 23:00 130.0 20
 0023 2014-01-02 16:00 130.0 20
 0023 2014-01-02 17:00 200.0 30.3
 0023 2014-01-02 18:00 303.0 30.3
```

Here is the output from the code:

```
0023 2014-01-01 21:00 90.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-01 22:00 80.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-01 23:00 130.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-02 16:00 130.0 20 1
0023 2014-01-02 17:00 200.0 30.3 1
0023 2014-01-02 18:00 303.0 30.3 1
```

but the desired output should be:

```
0023 2014-01-01 21:00 90.0 20   1  
0023 2014-01-01 22:00 80.0 20    1
0023 2014-01-01 23:00 130.0 20   1
0023 2014-01-02 16:00 130.0 20   2
0023 2014-01-02 17:00 200.0 30.3 2 
0023 2014-01-02 18:00 303.0 30.3 2
```

Sorry to post it as an answer, because it is too long to post as a comment.

Comment: I have added questions about the above to my first answer.